# how to find the latest documents with some condtions in MongoDB in python3?

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb

Im writing a program in python and i have a collection in my mongodb database with documents that each contains an id, a timestamp, an ip string and a status string like this :

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5b0edbb1094464505f1d2ce3"),
  "id": 20,
  "ip": "172.21.45.225",
  "port": 300,
  "status": "closed",
  "time": ISODate("2018-05-30T17:13:21.308Z")
}
```

by the way im using pymongo and djongo plug-in to connect my Django code to the database...

what i want to do is to select the records with status "open" for every diffrent ip which the record is the latest for that ip.
i come up with this solotion with sql but dont know how to do it in python and mongodb..

sql equivalent :

```
select r1.*
from myRecords r1, myRecords r2
where r1.status = "open" and r1.ip = r2.ip and r1.time > r2.time
```

Comment: Use $match to filtter documents with open status followed by $sort on time desc and $group on ip with $first to pick the latest record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at my code:

```
db.Testing.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match" :
            {   
                "status":"open"  
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" :
            {
                "_id": "$ip",  
                "id": { "$first": "$id"},  
                "ip": { "$first": "$ip"},
                "port": { "$first": "$port"},
                "status": { "$first": "$status"},
                "time": { "$max" : "$time"}
            }
        } 

    ]
    )
```

My test records:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db06f33f7b2f7cd819d21"), "id" : 20, "ip" : "172.21.45.225", "port" : 300, "status" : "closed", "time" : ISODate("2018-05-30T17:13:21.308Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db09733f7b2f7cd819d22"), "id" : 20, "ip" : "172.21.45.225", "port" : 300, "status" : "open", "time" : ISODate("2018-04-30T17:13:21.308Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db09b33f7b2f7cd819d23"), "id" : 20, "ip" : "172.21.45.225", "port" : 300, "status" : "open", "time" : ISODate("2018-03-30T17:13:21.308Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db09f33f7b2f7cd819d24"), "id" : 20, "ip" : "172.21.45.225", "port" : 300, "status" : "open", "time" : ISODate("2018-03-02T17:13:21.308Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db3c233f7b2f7cd819d25"), "id" : 20, "ip" : "172.21.44.225", "port" : 300, "status" : "open", "time" : ISODate("2018-03-30T17:13:21.308Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db3cb33f7b2f7cd819d26"), "id" : 20, "ip" : "172.21.44.225", "port" : 300, "status" : "open", "time" : ISODate("2018-04-30T17:13:21.308Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6db45333f7b2f7cd819d27"), "id" : 20, "ip" : "172.21.45.225", "port" : 300, "status" : "open", "time" : ISODate("2018-06-30T17:13:21.308Z") }
```

my result:

```
{ "time" : ISODate("2018-04-30T17:13:21.308Z"), "id" : 20, "ip" : "172.21.44.225", "port" : 300, "status" : "open" }
{ "time" : ISODate("2018-06-30T17:13:21.308Z"), "id" : 20, "ip" : "172.21.45.225", "port" : 300, "status" : "open" }
```